# Abort ajax load() from ajaxError

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

I have a lot of places in my code where a fragment is being loaded like that:

```
$('<div />').load('/some/thing/', function() { /* put it somewhere */ });
```

I also have an `ajaxError` handler:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (jqxhr.status = 401) {
        return alert('401!!');
    }
    if (jqxhr.status = 404) {
        return alert('404!!');
    }
    return alert('boo!');
});
```

However, even if `ajaxErro`r is triggered, the handler associated with the load is still fired. Is there any way to cancel the "completed" handler (which is what is used to fire the load handler) from `ajaxErro`r.

I have played around with Deferred, but the problem seems to be that I cannot get access to the `completeDeferred` object. In jQuery ajax.js:

```
jqXHR.complete = completeDeferred.add;
```

The `.add()` method, however, is useless. If only I could somehow just call the `.empty()` method of the underlying deferred object..

Any ideas?

Edit:  I do not care about aborting the HTTP request. It is done, fine. I only would like to keep the callback (that I attached via `.load()`) from firing.

Comment: Once error handler fires, the connection is already closed. There's nothing to abort...

Comment: From jQuery docs:

This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. **When a successful response is detected** (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Quite obviously, the docs are wrong. It attaches a complete handler, not success..

Comment: @LauriE: The docs are not wrong. A complete handler is attached, but *the replacement* happens only on success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either switch from `.load` to a more generalized AJAX method, or else detect failure from within your event handler.

To detect failure:

```
$('<div />').load('/some/thing/', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "error") return;
    // your existing code goes here
});
```

To use a more general method:

```
$.get("/some/thing/").done(function(response) {
    $("<div />").html(response) // etc etc
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! The second example is exactly what I need. 

I was hoping to avoid the if (status === 'error') in 100+ places. Someone will always forget to add it.. And the generic ajax() call is so verbose.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the final parameter of `load` is the equivalent of the `complete` parameter of `$.ajax`. That means that it is run whether the request was successful or not. I would suggest changing your `.load()` into a `$.ajax` call to give you more control of the logic flow. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/thing/',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        $('<div />').html(html).appendTo('#myElement');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is true, the more generic form allows the flexibility. I was hoping to avoid the verbosity by deploying a single ajax error handler, capable of cancelling even the completed handler. Seems like this is not possible.